# Image format change when doing direct Cut/Paste

Tags: bugs, interoperability, mac-os-x, clipboard

I usually produce graphics with Mathematica and then use Keynote (I am on a Mac running the latest Big Sur OS) for post processing. Until version 12.0.0.0 I would directly highlight the graphics in Mathematica, copy it (Cmd+C) and then paste it (Cmd+V) directly in Keynote; this would produce a perfect vector copy of the image which I could work on (looks to me a PDF). However in version 12.2.0.0 this does not work anymore: as I try to paste the image in Keynote I get a message saying that "*The image type is not supported on this device*".

Of course I could always export the figure to PDF and then import it in Keynote (there are however issues in 12.2.0.0 when exporting, which perhaps make for another question), but it is a much less practical work-flow.

So, I was wondering if any of you knows if this change in the figures' format stored in the Clipboard was intended/planned or it is a side effect/bug.

**EDIT 1:** Inspecting the clipboard content it looks like Mathematica 12.2.0.0 paste graphics in SVG format (which however appears as plain text in the clipboard) whereas Mathematica 12.0.0.0 is using TIFF (which is correctly interpreted as an image). Not sure there is a Mathematica option that allows to control the default format for images put in the clipboard.

Comment: Use `CopyToClipboard[Rasterize[...]]`. You can also increase the `RasterSize` option to increase the quality of the image.

Answer (score 5):

It is a known bug. Unfortunately, there is no way to change the current behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I found a solution (Mathematica v. 12.1.0 with Keynote 7.1) .

In Mathematica you can go to the menu bar and select

"Edit -> Copy as... -> PDF".

Works well and does not rasterize.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. However, there are major issues when exporting to PDF in 12.1 which makes the pointed out work-around sub-optimal, at least for me. I have actually downgraded to 12.0.0.0 to keep my usual workflows.

Comment: As to issues relating to the process of exporting to PDF I cannot comment. However, if the aim is just to copy and paste a vector image from Mathematica to Keynote with a simple mouse-click, the above work around does exactly that.